# How to declare complex array as property of another property Typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular, typescript

I am fairly new to Angular and Typescript, and I am trying to declare a property which has a complex array as one of its properties.  My attempt looks like this:

```
groupedItem: {
     customGroupId: string,
     cgName: string,
     category: [{ 
    customGroupItemId: string,
     name: string }]
 };
```

When I try to access the property

```
this.groupedItem.category.name
```

I get an error which states

```
Property 'name' does not exist on type '[{ customGroupItemId: string; name: string; }]'
```

It looks like it is there.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you observe your object **groupedItem** closely you'll see that **category** is in fact an array not an object, so you need to the following to access it:

```
this.groupedItem.category[0].name
```

Comment: Thank you!  That did it.